# matplotlib, seaborn version solving failed

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn

I am installing matplotlib, seaborn using poetry(poetry add matplotlib seaborn) but getting following error as below:

Because no versions of seaborn match >0.12.1,<0.13.0
and seaborn (0.12.1) depends on matplotlib (>=3.1,<3.6.1 || >3.6.1), seaborn (>=0.12.1,<0.13.0) requires matplotlib (>=3.1,<3.6.1 || >3.6.1).
And because no versions of matplotlib match >3.6.1,<4.0.0, seaborn (>=0.12.1,<0.13.0) requires matplotlib (>=3.1,<3.6.1 || >=4.0.0).
So, because project depends on both matplotlib (^3.6.1) and seaborn (^0.12.1), version solving failed.

what I am missing?

I was able to install either matplotlib or seaborn, But not both.
As I need both libraries, how should I install both using poetry?

Comment: Don't specify a version. At least with Anaconda, it will resolve and install the compatible versions.

Comment: Hi Trenton, Thanks for your time but project I am working on uses poetry and pip, so I need to stick with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error says, seaborn (0.12.1) depends on matplotlib (>=3.1,<3.6.1 || >3.6.1), i.e., `>=3.1, != 3.6.1`.

So you chould specify your environment as `matplotlib ^3.6.0` and `seaborn ^0.12.1`.

Comment: Hi mwaskom, Thanks. Explicitly specifying matplotlib version to 3.6.0 may work but this way I wont get latest matplotlib version ie 3.6.1

Comment: The carat syntax does not pin a specific version, it sets the minimal version and then allows upgrades so long as they don't increment the X level in an X.Y.Z semantic versioning scheme. https://python-poetry.org/docs/dependency-specification/#caret-requirements